# How to use a variable of the generic class in the data binding?

Tags: android, android-databinding

For example, I have the next model:

```
class Config<T: BaseClass> {
}
```

How can I declare a variable to it could accept a config with any type that inherits `BaseClass`? In short, I need a something like below:

```
<data>
    <variable name="config" type="Config&lt;? extends BaseClass&gt;"/>
</data>
```

Comment: Would it be enough to just use type Config<BaseClass>?

Comment: @JoshFeldman, nope, `Config<ChildClass>` can't be passed as `Config<BaseClass>`.